# error in script for counting number of occurences

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/sh
count=1
while read line
do
  found=$( grep M $line )
  if [ "$found" ]; then
    echo $count")" $line >> filesave.txt
  fi
  count=$((count+1))
done < log1.txt
```

but I am getting error like

```
./count.sh ./count.sh: syntax error at line 10: `found=$' unexpected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is unquoted variable reference `$line` in either

```
found=$( grep M $line )
```

and/or

```
echo $count")" $line >> filesave.txt`
```

in both cases `$line` should be double-quoted:

```
found=$( grep M "$line" )
echo $count")" "$line" >> filesave.txt`
```

The example uses the lines from `log1.txt` as filenames, which may not be what you want.  If you want to search each line read from `log.txt` for the string `M`, then you could use this:

```
found="$( echo "$line" | grep M )"
```

After this, `$found` would equal `$line` only if `$line` contained the letter `M`.

Comment: Great.  Good luck to you.  I sense this is a learning exercise for you so I didn't mention that I think `grep M log1.txt | cat -n` would yield _almost_ the same results.  If you accept this answer, please click the checkmark on the left.